# How to install a clock face on my desktop?

Tags: clock

I just installed 12.04 and would like to jazz it up a little with a nice-looking clock face on my desktop. Any suggestions...?   Thx

Comment: You need Conky. [This page on Google+](http://plus.google.com/communities/104794997718869399105/stream/c411c91a-2e51-4666-b3cc-13caf1c2dfc9) has some good examples

Comment: It would be great if someone has knocked something up with a unicode clock font [like this one](https://ocodo.github.io/ClockFace-font/ClockFace.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a desktop clock widget you can use [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/cairo-clock/):

[image]

There is also a nice [clock/weather indicator](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/get-htc-like-weather-clock-widget-in.html)